# Excel Formula to skip blank

Tags: excel, indexing, offset

I want to create dynamic formula to sort out values from column. Formula to fill in the cell when it contains text and skip the cell if that is blank and go to the next one.

Range is

```
-A
-(BLANK CELL)
-(BLANK CELL)
-D
-E
-F
-(BLANK CELL)
-H
-(BLANK CELL)
```

Result from the formula

```
-A
-E
-F
-H
```

Comment: Perhaps this will work for you: http://chandoo.org/wp/2014/01/13/combine-text-values-quick-tip/

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming your data is in `Column A` starting from `A1`. Enter the following **array formula** in Cell `B1`.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$A$15, SMALL(IF(ISBLANK($A$1:$A$15), "", ROW($A$1:$A$15)-MIN(ROW($A$1:$A$15))+1), ROW(A1))),"")
```

**Note**: This is an array formula so you'll have to commit it by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

See the image below:

[image]

Comment: Mrig Thanks a lot for your reply

Comment: But can you please help on " ctr+shift+enter ".

Comment: @SachinChhittarka - When you are done with writing a formula in a cell, you press `Enter`. But for an array formula, you'll have to keep `Ctrl` and `Shift` pressed together and then hit `Enter`. On doing this you should be able to see curly braces `{ }` around the formula. Note: Manually typing braces around a formula will not convert it into an array formula.